# Haskell: Why "Nothing<(4::Maybe Int)" gets an error but "Nothing< Just 4" pass?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

`Nothing` 's type could be `Maybe Int` and why couldn't it be compared with another `Maybe Int`?

And why `Nothing< Just 4` pass?

Comment: How can `4 :: Maybe Int` be valid? you're looking for `Just 4 :: Maybe Int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `Nothing` can be of type `Maybe Int` (or `Maybe String`, or `Maybe AnythingElse`).

Any two values of type `Maybe Int` can be compared.

Equality `==` is defined as one might expect: `Nothing` is only equal to `Nothing`, and `Just x` is only equal to `Just y` if `x==y`. This is defined in the `Eq` instance for `Maybe a`, which is automatically imported since it is in the Haskell `Prelude`.

Similarly, there is an `Ord (Maybe a)` instance as well in the `Prelude`. This instance defines `<` between `Maybe Int`s so that `Nothing` is the minimum element (`<` anything else), while two values `Just x` and `Just y` are compared according to whether `x < y`.

So, `Nothing < Just 4` is true.

---

The code `Nothing<(4::Maybe Int)` gives you an error since `4` is an `Int` (technically, it is any type in the `Num` type class), but `4` is not a `Maybe Int`. If you write `4 :: String` or `4 :: [Int]` or `4 :: Int -> Int` you will get a similar type error.

The `Maybe Int` type contains only the values

```
Nothing
Just 0
Just 1
Just -1
Just 2
Just -2
...
```

(and some bottoms, which I omit.)

The value `4` is not a value of type `Maybe Int`. `Just 4` is instead one of such values.

Answer (score 7):

There's a simple type error in your expression:  `4` does not have type `Maybe Int`.

Comment: but even if I declare 4 like this 4::Maybe Int, it still doesn't work

Comment: plus, if I compare literal 4 with a Maybe Int,the type inference should know what type I want, right?

Comment: @sqd - There are only two ways to construct a value of `Maybe Int` - `Nothing` or using the `Just` constructor. The compiler will not do any conversions for you automatically.

Comment: @sqd i don't know what the confusion is, but if you are bringing the ideas about type casting from other languages, then that's where the mistake is. `4` can not be forced to `Maybe Int`. In fact, you never cast types in Haskell - only convert from values of some type to the other type (for example, can't cast `float` to `int` - got to explicitly convert them). Sometimes you do need to qualify the type, if the expression is too polymorphic, but that's not type casting in the sense of C or Java.

Comment: @AndrewC, that's quite a sensible instance. I wonder if it should be added to base.

Comment: @dfeuer Perhaps. You could define `Fractional` and `Integral` to avoid dividing by zero and give `Nothing` instead. It's a pity you can't check whether there's also a `Bounded` instance and replace overflows etc with `Nothing` too.

Comment: @dfeuer But the one that's really bugging me is that it seems the AMP is being done without putting `<$>` in the prelude. Just a little `<$>` without importing `Control.Applicative` or `Data.Functor` wouldn't hurt people while they're editing out `<*>` anyway and would make me very happy!